# Exclude certain values in string field when labelling in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I am trying to label a field on a map but exclude certain text strings from appearing. Specifically, I am working with pipes and their labels. The string values include the pipe size and material so one valaue could be (6" PVC) for example. Some of the data has 0" as the label and I am trying to remove that from the actual labeling.

Is there a way to write a python script that excludes the 0" string values from labeling but keeps all the other values?

The field name is [PIPE_IN_MA].

---

I decided to go with VB script and figured out what my mistake was. I only had one quoation mark when I shouldve had two. Here is the finished code:

```
Function FindLabel ([PIPE_IN_MA])
If [PIPE_IN_MA]="0""" Then

          FindLabel = ""
Else
FindLabel = [PIPE_IN_MA]
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I decided to go with VB script and figured out what my mistake was. I only had one quoation mark when I shouldve had two. Here is the finished code:                                                                                                                      
Function FindLabel ([PIPE_IN_MA])
If [PIPE_IN_MA]="0""" Then

          FindLabel = ""
Else
FindLabel = [PIPE_IN_MA]
End If
End Function

Answer (score 1):

I see you have some code that works in VB script, I believe python is easier, strings can use single `'` or double `"` as long as both ends match. If you use the opposing identifiers strings like `'6" pipe'` or `"Mawson's Hut"` are valid. If you have both in a string the quote character that matches the string identifier is escaped (C style) so `'6" pipe from Mawson\'s Hut'` prints `6" pipe from Mawson's Hut` which I find easier to read than the VB `"""` to utilize the string identifier.

I have found that often another value also needs to be excluded and this is where python really shines:

```
StringsToSkip = ['0"','lead pipe'] # as an example I've added another string to skip

def FindLabel ( [PIPE_IN_MA] ):
    global StringsToSkip # saves a few nanoseconds by not reinitializing the list on each iteration
    
    # look for a string match in the list. Python is case sensitive so 
    # I use [field].lower() to perform all string comparisons in lower case
    if [PIPE_IN_MA].lower() in StringsToSkip:
        # value matches an element in the list, return None which is a special 
        #  identifier in python with a value close to vbNull
        return None          
    else:
        # not a match, return the string to label
        return [PIPE_IN_MA]
```

Be careful with the size of the list of strings to skip as the `in` and `not in` operators are very slow, if you start with a bunch of similar strings it might be best to use [a label query](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm) to exclude similar strings, for example if you don't want to label 'Disused' and Unused a query like `PIPE_IN_MA NOT LIKE '%used'` to exclude any value that ends with `used`. Which is how I would exclude just one label value, using the label class query for default `PIPE_IN_MA <> '0"'` which possibly be the the simplest way of achieving your result:
[image: Setting up layer for label classes]

Which brings up a dialog:

[image: The query expression to exclude a single value]

As the execution of a SQL query is often faster than running a scipt.